# .NET How to Send HttpClient Get Request on Specified IP address in same domain

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpclient, webrequest

I have a problem. I migrate from WebRequest to HttpClient.
In WebRequest i simple implement:

```
var webRequest =   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://111.111.111.111:8080/method");
webRequest.Host = "mysite:8080.com";
```

And http requests works fine.

Then i replace WebRequest on HttpClient, and faced with the problem.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "mysite:8080.com";
var result = await client.GetAsync("http://111.111.111.111:8080/method", cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false); // rise 404 error
```

GetAsync rise 404 in this case. HttpClient can't send requests on specified ip's?

Comment: It works for me. For anyone else it initially didn't work because when running ASP.NET Core console app I forgot to change the binding from "http://localhost:5000" to "http://*:5000" to allow requests to be handled from ip address instead instead of localhost.

Answer (score 2):

This might be old, but to those who can bump in this error, here you can use this method :

```
static async void getHttpClient()
    {
        string mUrl = "http://192.168.1.111/method";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(mURL))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (result != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            } else
            {
                 //
                 // ERROR
                 // 
            }
        }
    }
```

happy codings

Comment: This is not the setting the IP of the requestor.